# tsc report error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Boolean'

Tags: node.js, typescript1.8, typescript-typings, tsc

I'm a newbie to node and typescript, I'm getting trouble when compile my typescript project. I've read serval posts on SO, but still cannot resolve my problem.

Could anyone help me with this?

***tsconfig.json:***

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noLib": false
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

***typings/index.d.ts:***

```
/// <reference path="globals/angular-protractor/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/core-js/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/koa/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/node/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/require/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/sequelize/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/typescript/index.d.ts" />
```

***Reported error:***

```
>pats-test-report-client@1.0.0 compile C:\WorkSpace\WeiHao\Git\dev-pats-test-report\server
>typings install && tsc && concurrently


├── angular-protractor (global)
├── core-js (global)
├── jasmine (global)
├── koa (global)
├── node (global)
├── require (global)
├── selenium-webdriver (global)
├── sequelize (global)
└── typescript (global)

../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(17,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(26,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '[Symbol.toStringTag]'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(33,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(61,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'hasInstance'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(67,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'isConcatSpreadable'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(73,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'iterator'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(79,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'match'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(85,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'replace'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(91,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'search'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(97,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'species'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(103,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'split'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(109,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'toPrimitive'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(115,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'toStringTag'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(121,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'unscopables'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(219,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'name'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(237,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(272,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(279,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(305,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '[Symbol.unscopables]'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(565,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(566,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(709,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '[Symbol.toStringTag]'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(795,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(823,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(833,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(849,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(861,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(871,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(886,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(891,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '[Symbol.toStringTag]'.
../../../../../Users/rick/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(1282,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(3,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(67,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'name'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(127,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '[Symbol.unscopables]'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(244,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(258,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(293,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(300,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(439,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '[Symbol.toStringTag]'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(446,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(474,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'hasInstance'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(480,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'isConcatSpreadable'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(486,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'iterator'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(492,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'match'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(498,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'replace'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(504,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'search'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(510,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'species'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(516,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'split'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(522,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'toPrimitive'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(528,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'toStringTag'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(534,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'unscopables'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(591,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '[Symbol.toStringTag]'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(595,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '[Symbol.toStringTag]'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(610,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(616,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(627,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(633,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(648,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(662,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(673,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(674,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(786,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
```

**I've tried set "noLib" option in tsconfig.json as true. And it will lead to another error**:

```
> pats-test-report-client@1.0.0 compile C:\WorkSpace\WeiHao\Git\dev-pats-test-report\server
> typings install && tsc && concurrently


├── angular-protractor (global)
├── core-js (global)
├── jasmine (global)
├── koa (global)
├── node (global)
├── require (global)
├── selenium-webdriver (global)
├── sequelize (global)
└── typescript (global)

error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Boolean'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'IArguments'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'TemplateStringsArray'.
```

**I understand why error TS2300 is reported when noLib is set to false. But DO NOT know why error TS2318 is reported when noLib is set to true.**

Answer (score 9):

It might be that you are missing es2015 in your tsconfig.json. Edit as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "lib": ["es2015"]
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I had this error when doing typescript on nodejs.  To fix, I had to install type information for nodejs:

```
npm i @types/node
```

Basically I think typescript doesn't know if you are in the browser or on node.js, so by default, it doesn't include type information for either platform.